# Forge viewer version 6.3.4 doesn't show newly released document browser extension

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I upgraded the forge viewer version of my solution to 6.* to utilize the latest released feature "Document browser extension" as it mentions [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v-63)

This extension doesn't appear for me, please help.

Comment: Is ```viewer.model.getDocumentNode()``` returning null? If so the Document Browser won't work

Comment: Yes, viewer.model.getDocumentNode() returns null. Any specific reason for it, When does it return null?

Comment: Usually it returns null when there's no model/viewable to show. Is your model loaded properly? Can you try [load a model](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v6/reference/javascript/viewer3d/#loadmodel-url-options-onsuccesscallback-onerrorcallback) and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes, model is loading properly and I have used loadModel method to do the same

Comment: As pointed by the answer below you will also need to load the extension as well as the document node explicitly upon loading the model successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work after some experimenting.
Here is my workflow in case you still need it.

First, initialize the viewer:

```
// initialize the viewer
Autodesk.Viewing.Initializer(adOptions, () => {
  // when initialized, call loading function
  this.loadDocument(encodedUrn);
});
```

Then, load your document in the function called above:

```
// load the document from the urn
Autodesk.Viewing.Document.load(
  encodedUrn,
  this.onDocumentLoadSuccess,
  this.onDocumentLoadFailure,
);
```

In the success callback you can now do the following:

```
onDocumentLoadSuccess(doc) {
  // get the geometries of the document
  const geometries = doc.getRoot().search({ type: 'geometry' });

  // Choose any of the available geometries
  const initGeom = geometries[0];

  // and prepare config for the viewer application
  const config = {
    extensions: ['Autodesk.DocumentBrowser'],
  };

  // create the viewer application and bind the reference of the viewerContainer to 'this.viewer'
  this.viewer = new Autodesk.Viewing.Private.GuiViewer3D(
    this.viewerContainer,
    config,
  );

  // start the viewer
  this.viewer.start();

  // load a node in the fetched document
  this.viewer.loadDocumentNode(doc.getRoot().lmvDocument, initGeom);
}
```

I hope this will make it work for you as well. What helped me was the reference to the loadDocumentNode function in [this blog post](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewer-release-notes-v-63).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.  I just checked it, will try this soon.

Comment: @BalajiPastapure if this helped you or worked for you, consider accepting my answer as solution please :)